# How to train tesseract to reduce the number of empty outputs

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tesseract, python-tesseract

Version Info:

```
tesseract 4.00.00alpha
leptonica-1.74.4
```

I am fine tuning [eng.trainedata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/blob/master/eng.traineddata) on a custom data-set using the following Makefile. I use latin.unicharset as a unicharset for training ( I am training my model to generalize on set of characters that it has not yet seen ).

```
export

SHELL := /bin/bash
HOME := $(PWD)
TESSDATA = $(HOME)/tessdata
LANGDATA = $(HOME)/langdata

# Train directory
TRAIN := $(HOME)/train_data

# Name of the model to be built
MODEL_NAME = eng

# Name of the model to continue from
CONTINUE_FROM = eng

TESSDATA_REPO = _best

# Normalization Mode - see src/training/language_specific.sh for details 
NORM_MODE = 2


# BEGIN-EVAL makefile-parser --make-help Makefile

help:
    @echo ""
    @echo "  Targets"
    @echo ""
    @echo "    unicharset       Create unicharset"
    @echo "    lists            Create lists of lstmf filenames for training and eval"
    @echo "    training         Start training"
    @echo "    proto-model      Build the proto model"
    @echo "    leptonica        Build leptonica"
    @echo "    tesseract        Build tesseract"
    @echo "    tesseract-langs  Download tesseract-langs"
    @echo "    langdata         Download langdata"
    @echo "    clean            Clean all generated files"
    @echo ""
    @echo "  Variables"
    @echo ""
    @echo "    MODEL_NAME         Name of the model to be built"
    @echo "    CORES              No of cores to use for compiling leptonica/tesseract"
    @echo "    LEPTONICA_VERSION  Leptonica version. Default: $(LEPTONICA_VERSION)"
    @echo "    TESSERACT_VERSION  Tesseract commit. Default: $(TESSERACT_VERSION)"
    @echo "    LANGDATA_VERSION   Tesseract langdata version. Default: $(LANGDATA_VERSION)"
    @echo "    TESSDATA_REPO      Tesseract model repo to use. Default: $(TESSDATA_REPO)"
    @echo "    TRAIN              Train directory"
    @echo "    RATIO_TRAIN        Ratio of train / eval training data"

# END-EVAL

# Ratio of train / eval training data
RATIO_TRAIN := 0.90

ALL_BOXES = data/all-boxes
ALL_LSTMF = data/all-lstmf

# Create unicharset
unicharset: data/unicharset

# Create lists of lstmf filenames for training and eval
lists: $(ALL_LSTMF) data/list.train data/list.eval

data/list.train: $(ALL_LSTMF)
    total=`cat $(ALL_LSTMF) | wc -l` \
       no=`echo "$$total * $(RATIO_TRAIN) / 1" | bc`; \
       head -n "$$no" $(ALL_LSTMF) > "$@"

data/list.eval: $(ALL_LSTMF)
    total=`cat $(ALL_LSTMF) | wc -l` \
       no=`echo "($$total - $$total * $(RATIO_TRAIN)) / 1" | bc`; \
       tail -n "+$$no" $(ALL_LSTMF) > "$@"

# Start training
training: data/$(MODEL_NAME).traineddata

data/unicharset: $(ALL_BOXES)
    combine_tessdata -u $(TESSDATA)/$(CONTINUE_FROM).traineddata  $(TESSDATA)/$(CONTINUE_FROM).
    unicharset_extractor --output_unicharset "$(TRAIN)/my.unicharset" --norm_mode $(NORM_MODE) "$(ALL_BOXES)"
#   merge_unicharsets data/$(START_MODEL)/$(START_MODEL).lstm-unicharset $(GROUND_TRUTH_DIR)/my.unicharset  "$@"

$(ALL_BOXES): $(sort $(patsubst %.tif,%.box,$(wildcard $(TRAIN)/*.tif)))
    find $(TRAIN) -name '*.box' -exec cat {} \; > "$@"

$(TRAIN)/%.box: $(TRAIN)/%.tif $(TRAIN)/%.gt.txt
    python generate_line_box.py -i "$(TRAIN)/$*.tif" -t "$(TRAIN)/$*.gt.txt" > "$@"

$(ALL_LSTMF): $(sort $(patsubst %.tif,%.lstmf,$(wildcard $(TRAIN)/*.tif)))
    find $(TRAIN) -name '*.lstmf' -exec echo {} \; | sort -R -o "$@"

$(TRAIN)/%.lstmf: $(TRAIN)/%.box
    tesseract $(TRAIN)/$*.tif $(TRAIN)/$* --psm 7 lstm.train


# Build the proto model
proto-model: data/$(MODEL_NAME)/$(MODEL_NAME).traineddata

data/$(MODEL_NAME)/$(MODEL_NAME).traineddata: $(LANGDATA) data/unicharset
    combine_lang_model \
      --input_unicharset data/unicharset \
      --script_dir $(LANGDATA) \
      --words $(LANGDATA)/$(MODEL_NAME)/$(MODEL_NAME).wordlist \
      --numbers $(LANGDATA)/$(MODEL_NAME)/$(MODEL_NAME).numbers \
      --puncs $(LANGDATA)/$(MODEL_NAME)/$(MODEL_NAME).punc \
      --output_dir data/ \
      --lang $(MODEL_NAME)

data/checkpoints/$(MODEL_NAME)_checkpoint: unicharset lists proto-model
    mkdir -p data/checkpoints
    lstmtraining \
      --continue_from   $(TESSDATA)/$(CONTINUE_FROM).lstm \
      --old_traineddata $(TESSDATA)/$(CONTINUE_FROM).traineddata \
      --traineddata data/$(MODEL_NAME)/$(MODEL_NAME).traineddata \
      --model_output data/checkpoints/$(MODEL_NAME) \
      --debug_interval -1 \
      --train_listfile data/list.train \
      --eval_listfile data/list.eval \
      --sequential_training \
      --max_iterations 88186

data/$(MODEL_NAME).traineddata: data/checkpoints/$(MODEL_NAME)_checkpoint
    lstmtraining \
    --stop_training \
    --continue_from $^ \
    --old_traineddata $(TESSDATA)/$(CONTINUE_FROM).traineddata \
    --traineddata data/$(MODEL_NAME)/$(MODEL_NAME).traineddata \
    --model_output $@

# Clean all generated files
clean:
    find data/train -name '*.box' -delete
    find data/train -name '*.lstmf' -delete
    rm -rf data/all-*
    rm -rf data/list.*
    rm -rf data/$(MODEL_NAME)
    rm -rf data/unicharset
    rm -rf data/checkpoints
```

Despite training tesseract for a considerable number of epochs it gives empty output for a significant number of images in the training data ( these images have > 100 pixels image_width and image_height ).

So I have 2 questions:

```
1. Is this a known issue with tesseract version 4.0.0alpha and fixed it in the future releases.
2. If its not a bug. How should I proceed with training to make sure that the number of images for which tesseract gives empty output is minimized.
```